# Solr regex search incorrect results

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 4.1 and trying a regex pattern with Query. The sample data is

```
56% AB, 78% DC
65% AB, 55% IJ
70% AB, 35% LJ
```

I am trying this pattern `/([1-6][0-9]% AB)/`, this is not working so i tried

```
/([1-6][1-9])??AB/
```

it shows all the above as it is not using AND operator when the pattern applies and it is applying OR operator for each character. For Eg: the below results will also appear

```
77% DD, 89% FF
```

Has anybody tried regex with Solr 4.0 and above?

Comment: What is the fieldType of your data? Is it string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your field is of `string` type, you can try:
`/[1-6][0-9]. AB.*/`

(I tried the same regex search on a `text` field, but it did not match, most likely because of tokenization.)

I know this is a looser match than what you are looking for, since it will match any character for the 3rd position, but the Solr REST API does not like % inside the regex. (I am not sure if SolrJ or another client library can handle that.) With that said, this pattern should definitely exclude

`77% DD, 89% FF`

and maybe all you need.

**UPDATE**

This is the precise solution for your question. Use percent encodings for % (%25) and space (%20) and you will get exactly what you are looking for.

`/[1-6][0-9]%25%20AB.*/`

Comment: Thanks Arun for your reply. Currently i am trying the query through Solr Admin and not through any API. But obviously we will use SolrNet API to connect to Solr Index.

I am using `text_general` as field type, after you reply i changed to string and tried. The above solution is not working with both `string` and `text_general`

Comment: i missed to mention that above is a multivalued field. So `77%DD, 89% FF` are two different values. I guess the problem is not in percentage and it is `8` **9** `% FF`. The second position is matching with the regular expression and that is why the results are showing up. 

This is what i am trying to say that the regular expression is not using `AND` operator for each character and it is using `OR` operator for each character. So if any one character matches in the regular expression it is showing the results. My assumption might be wrong if any documentation or some examples are there.

Comment: I don't know what to expect with a regex match on a multi-valued field. It may match across multiple values and do some weird logic like you are seeing. Your best bet may be to store all the values as a single comma-separated string and then do the regex match. Unfortunately I could not find any documentation on this either and just had to try it myself.

Comment: It is working after i changed the data type to string and multivalued = true. The regex pattern i used is `/([0-9][0-5])% AB/`. You have given me the idea, so i accept your answer.

Comment: One problem with multi-values fields is that you won't know which value matched your query. If that is something you don't need to know, then I guess you are fine.

Comment: Yes, in my case if any one matches is fine and i don't need to know which value it matches. Thanks.